# What is ATEActivity in android?

Tags: java, android-activity

I am studying android by reading open-source codes.
I am reading "timber music player" on Github.
here is the address

[timper music player](https://github.com/naman14/Timber)

When you download it, you will have "BaseActivity" in "com.naman14.timber.activities" Folder.
It extends "ATEActivity," which extends "AppCompatActivity."
When you read the code of "ATEActivity.class" on Android Studio, you will have the message, "Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 51.0 (Java 7)"

My Question is why "BaseActivity" extends "ATEActivity", instead of "AppCampatActivity" directly?
What is the difference between extending "AppCompatActivity" via "ATEActivity" and extending it directly??
What is it for??
There is no document about it on Android developers web-site.
Where can I learn about it?

Comment: ATEActivity is a class in an android library https://github.com/garretyoder/app-theme-engine/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/afollestad/appthemeengine/ATEActivity.java. So, the timber music player is using that library, https://github.com/naman14/Timber/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L78

Comment: @PeterHaddad THank you!!

Answer (score 0):

ATEActivity is a part of the App theme engine, which was putted down from github from its developers.
The App Theme Engine was designed for enabling user prefered layouts. So the user can set up his own color scheme for the app.
For my opinion: changing the inheritance row(not inheriting from AppCompatActivity directly) for such a use case is sign for bad implementation.